# How to deploy React application that makes server calls through Node/Express to IIS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, deployment

I have a React application that makes calls to a server.js file - these calls are requests to get data from a database with the use of queries (I'm using MSSQL).

Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())

var database =    {
    server: xxx,
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: ‘xxx’,
            password: ‘xxx’,
        },
    },
    options: {
        database: ‘xxx’,
        encrypt: false,
    },
}

app.get(‘/gettingInfo’, function(req, res)    {
    sql.connect(database, function(err)  {
        if (err)    {
            console.log("ERROR HERE")
            console.log(err);
        }

        var request = new sql.Request();  
    const finalRoomQuery = [query];

        request.query(finalRoomQuery, function(err, recordset)  {
            if (err)    {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});


var server = app.listen(5000, function ()   {
    console.log('Server is running...');
});
```

Below is sample bit of code from one of my components that retrieves data from my server.js:

```
getData = () => {
        if (this.mounted === true)   {
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/gettingInfo')
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => this.setState({data: results}))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    }
```

When I run `node server.js` in my project directory, followed my `npm start`, my react application is able to retrieve data and render it appropriately.

I'm working on deploying my application. I ran `npm run build` to build the application, and I've deployed it to IIS. This is where I'm running into problems - if I don't have localhost:5000 running on my machine (i.e if `node server.js` is not entered), my application cannot query for the data needed, I get a (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. However, when I have localhost:5000 running, the application on IIS will run as expected.

My question is: how can I host this server.js file as well, and/or how can I configure this project so that I don't have to have localhost:5000 running for the application to work properly? I apologize if this is some straight forward fix or if I'm missing something very basic, this is my first experience with Web Dev.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you are not sending response back in all cases.

```
app.get(‘/gettingInfo’, function(req, res)    {
    sql.connect(database, function(err)  {
        if (err)    {
            console.log("ERROR HERE")
            console.log(err);
            return res.send("Error Message");
        }

        var request = new sql.Request();  
        const finalRoomQuery = [query];

        request.query(finalRoomQuery, function(err, recordset)  {
            if (err)    {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send("Error Message");
            }
            return res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey Muhammad, thanks for your response! I was wondering, is this the only problem? I ask because the error I got was that the connection was refused, and I don’t know if adding an extra res.send is the only fix.

Comment: Are you using both, react and node in one single project?

Comment: If yes try looking at proxy, this is generally not a good practice. Please separate the projects start them individually

Comment: Muhammad, yes. This is a front end and back end application. If I separate these, would I have to have both projects running (separate websites) on IIS? What’s the next step, to achieve the functionality I want? (both the server and website are running independently and the application can fetch the data automatically)

Comment: No not IIS, just run yarn start / npm start locally and for deployment you can host your react app on firebase and nodejs app on heroku for free

Answer (score 0):

You need to use process managers like PM2 and run your server in that console.
[pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: hey Vijay, thanks for your response. I was wondering if I can still host this on IIS?